# Xamarin.Forms Custom DateTime BindableProperty BindingPropertyChangedDelegate

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, propertychanged

I have been working through Ed Snider's book, Mastering Xamarin.Forms. Page 71 instructs to create a class, DatePickerEmtryCell, that inherits from EntryCell. 
It shows to add the following DateTime BindableProperty, but this method is now deprecated and generates an error.

```
public static readonly BindableProperty DateProperty = BindableProperty.Create<DatePickerEntryCell, DateTime>(p =>
     p.Date,
     DateTime.Now,
     propertyChanged: new BindableProperty.BindingPropertyChangedDelegate<DateTime>(DatePropertyChanged));
```

I think that I am on the right track with the following, but I am not sure how to finish it and am completely stuck:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty DateProperty =
     BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Date), typeof(DateTime), typeof(DatePickerEntryCell), default(DateTime),
      BindingMode.TwoWay, null, new BindableProperty.BindingPropertyChangedDelegate(
```

I thought that it would be this

```
    new BindableProperty.BindingPropertyChangedDelegate(DatePickerEntryCell.DatePropertyChanged), null, null);
```

but this is incorrect, along with countless other permutations that I have tried. 
I would love some instruction.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `DateProperty` is static, `propertyChanged` delegate should be static as well. Since it is of type `BindingPropertyChangedDelegate`. You can try it this way:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty DateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: nameof(Date),
        returnType: typeof(DateTime),
        declaringType: typeof(DatePickerEntryCell),
        defaultValue: default(DateTime),
        defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
        validateValue: null,
        propertyChanged: OnDatePropertyChanged);
```

Now, from the delegate, you should have access to the `BindableObject` which represents your `DatePickerEntryCell` element. You also have access to the old/new values. Here's how to retrieve the control from the delegate:

```
public static void OnDatePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var control = bindable as DatePickerEntryCell;
    if (control != null){
        // do something with this control...
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!